# Enabling GroupBox on NumericUpDown value change

Tags: c#, groupbox, numericupdown

I am creating a Pizza menu for an assignment and I want to enable a groupbox when a NumericUpDown value is changed to 1, I have this working for my Cheese Pizza, however the code used for this doesn't seem to be working for any of the other group boxes.

```
        private void numCheese_ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numCheese.Value == 0)
            {
                gbCheesePizza.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                gbCheesePizza.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

```
        private void numSeafood_ValueChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (numSeafood.Value == 0)
            {
                gbSeafoodPizza.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                gbSeafoodPizza.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Code to disable the groupbox on form load

```
        public Delivery()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            gbCheesePizza.Enabled = false;
            gbHamPizza.Enabled = false;
            gbMeatPizza.Enabled = false;
            gbSeafoodPizza.Enabled = false;
            gbVeggyPizza.Enabled = false;
        }
```

**Code from Delivery.Designer.cs**

```
           // 
            // numSeafood
            // 
            this.numSeafood.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(812, 64);
            this.numSeafood.Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
            10,
            0,
            0,
            0});
            this.numSeafood.Name = "numSeafood";
            this.numSeafood.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(43, 20);
            this.numSeafood.TabIndex = 5;
```

Comment: When you put breakpoint in it does it even hits?

Comment: No @AleksaRistic

Comment: That means your event handler is not initialized properly.... Could you go to formname.designer.cs and find part where is code about `numSeafood` and copy/paste it in your question

Comment: Added @AleksaRistic

Comment: There is no function assigned to event of that object. Add `this.numSeafood.ValueChanged += numSeafood_ValueChanged;`

Comment: This worked. Thank you @AleksaRistic!

Answer (score 0):

No function was assigned to the event of my object.
Adding `this.numSeafood.ValueChanged += numSeafood_ValueChanged;` fixed the issue.